# How to stop one thread on the condition another has stopped?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm creating a local chat app with sockets & threading in python. I'm new to threading so exception handling in my code isn't the best. I've got it so that when the disconnect/ kick command is entered the receive thread breaks however I have the sending thread still running. I've tried global boolean variables, is_alive function etc yet the sending thread still runs.

Can someone help me kill the second thread on the condition the first one ends.

Here is my most recent attempt on my client code, the server side works already.

```
import socket
import threading
import pickle
import sys

global conn
conn = bool

class ChatClient: #creates the clients connection to the server
    # admin passes a command to the server which allows commands 
    def __init__(self, nickname, host, port, roomcode):
        self.nickname = str(nickname)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.roomcode = str(roomcode)
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.recieve = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        self.sending = threading.Thread(target=self.send)

    def connect(self): #connects to the server and starts a trhead to recieve data
        self.client_socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
        print("Connected to the server")
        conn = True
        self.client_socket.send(self.nickname.encode())
        self.client_socket.recv(1024)
        self.client_socket.send(self.roomcode.encode())

        response = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        if response == "/adminReady":
            print(f"You're the Admin of Room: {self.roomcode}")
        elif response == "/ready":
            print(f"You've joined the Room: {self.roomcode}")
        elif response == "/wait":
            print(f"You're request to join Room: {self.roomcode} is pending approval")
            print("COMMANDS YOU CAN USE:\n/waitDisconnect - to finish waiting for approval\n")


        if conn == True:
            self.recieve.start()
            if conn == True:
                self.sending.start()
        else:
            exit()


    def receive(self): #recieves data & breaks connection
        while True:
            try:
                message = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
                if message == "/viewRequests":
                    self.client_socket.send(bytes(".","utf-8"))
                    response = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
                    if response == "/sendingData":
                        self.client_socket.send(b"/readyForData")
                        data = pickle.loads(self.client_socket.recv(1024))
                        if data == set():
                            print("No pending requests")
                        else:
                            print("Pending Requests")
                            for request in data:
                                print(request)

                elif message == "/approveRequest":
                    self.client_socket.send(bytes(".", "utf-8"))
                    response = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
                    if response == "/proceed":
                        usernameToAllow = input("Please enter username to allow in the room: ")
                        self.client_socket.send(bytes(usernameToAllow, "utf-8"))
                        print(self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode())
                    else:
                        print(response)

                elif message == "/disconnect":
                    self.client_socket.send(bytes(".", "utf-8"))
                    self.client_socket.close()
                    conn == False
                    break
                
                elif message == "/waitdisconnect":
                    self.client_socket.close()
                    conn == False
                    break

                elif message == "/findAdmin":
                    self.client_socket.send(bytes(".", "utf-8"))
                    print(pickle.loads(self.client_socket.recv(1024)))

                elif message == "/onlineUsers":
                    self.client_socket.send(bytes(".", "utf-8"))
                    data = pickle.loads(self.client_socket.recv(1024))
                    print("Online Room Users:")
                    for user in data:
                        print(user)
                
                elif message == "/kickUser":
                    self.client_socket.send(bytes(".", "utf-8"))
                    response = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
                    if response == "/proceed":
                        usernameToKick = input("Username to kick: ")
                        self.client_socket.send(bytes(usernameToKick, "utf-8"))
                    else:
                        print(response)
                
                elif message == "/kicked":
                    print("You've been kicked from the room")
                    self.client_socket.close()
                    conn == False
                    break

                else:
                    print(message)

            except:
                print("An error occurred")
                self.client_socket.close()
                raise SystemExit(0)

    def send(self): #sends data to other users 
        if conn:
            while True:
                message = input("")
                self.client_socket.send(message.encode())
        else:
            return conn == False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nickname = input("Enter username: ")
    roomcode = int(input("Enter roomcode: "))
    client = ChatClient(nickname, 'localhost', 55555, roomcode)
    client.connect()
    raise SystemExit(0)
```

Here's the error, after i type /disconnect i want it so the whole program ends & you cannot type anything else in.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA6bM.png)

Comment: If you want to close the entire app, the system exit function should do that. Example: import sys;sys.exit()

Comment: i tried sys.exit already - it just goes to the second thread still @SupaMaggie70b

Comment: Are you sure you called sys.exit in the main thread?